How to disable irregular tab shading in VS Code
In VS Code in Python I have my autoformatter set to indent function parameters in-line if I make a line break between them, like so:

However something else is making that shading on line 84 and I can't find it in settings. I think it appears whenever my indentation isn't a multiple of 4 spaces, but how do I turn it off?

In this case it turned out to be an extension called indent-rainbow, not a built in VS Code setting!
